# Dynamic link based on country input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to build a dynamic link in JavaScript for a web form when the user chooses a country from a picklist the Privaci Policy will change dynamically, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's the HTML and JavaScript code I'm using:

```
` <div class="htmlSection" id="tfa_34">
          <div class="htmlContent" id="tfa_34-HTML">
            <span style="font-size: 14.4px;">Your personal information will be processed in accordance with our&nbsp;</span>
            <a style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(61, 85, 221); font-size: 14.4px;" href="https://www.example.com/uk/disclaimer-policies/privacy/" target="_blank"></a>
            <a style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14.4px;" target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com/au/disclaimer-policies/privacy/"></a>
            <a style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14.4px;" href="https://www.example.com/sg/disclaimer-policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>
            <span style="font-size: 14.4px;">.</span>
          </div>
        </div>`
```

I've tried adding the JavaScript bit of code which targets the country fields and assignes it to the correct link but it doesn't work. I have a script that should update a Privacy Policy link based on the selected country in a dropdown menu. However, it doesn't work as expected, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried the following JavaScript code:

```
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Get references to the picklist fields
    var countrySelect = document.getElementById('tfa_27'); // Country of business

    // Function to update the Privacy Policy link based on the selected country
    function updatePrivacyPolicyLink() {
        // Get the Privacy Policy link
        var privacyLink = document.querySelector('.htmlSection #tfa_34 a[href*="https://www.example.com/sg/disclaimer-policies/privacy/"]');

        // Define the Privacy Policy URLs for each country
        var privacyPolicyUrls = {
            'New Zealand': 'https://www.example.com/sg/disclaimer-policies/privacy/',
            'Australia': 'https://www.example.com/au/disclaimer-policies/privacy/'
        };

        // Get the selected country
        var selectedCountry = countrySelect.value;

        // Set the Privacy Policy link's href attribute based on the selected country
        if (selectedCountry === 'tfa_35') { // New Zealand
            privacyLink.href = privacyPolicyUrls['New Zealand'];
        } else if (selectedCountry === 'tfa_36') { // Australia
            privacyLink.href = privacyPolicyUrls['Australia'];
        } else {
            // Default to a generic Privacy Policy URL if neither country is selected
            privacyLink.href = 'https://www.example.com/uk/disclaimer-policies/privacy/';
        }
    }

    // Add an event listener to the country select field to update the link when the user makes a selection
    countrySelect.addEventListener('change', updatePrivacyPolicyLink);

    // Call the function initially to set the link based on the initial value of the picklist field
    updatePrivacyPolicyLink();
});`
```

Comment: `.htmlSection #tfa_34` would select an element with the ID `tfa_34`, that is a _descendant_ of an element with the class `htmlSection` - doesn't look like you have that though, you have _one_ element that has both this class and ID. So the correct selector for that (if there is even any need to be that overly specific in the first place, selection _just_ by ID would probably do?) would be either `.htmlSection#tfa_34`, or the other way around, `#tfa_34.htmlSection`

Comment: none of them are working unfortunatelly, I can add and id like this  <a id="privacy_policy" href="https://www.example.com/sg/disclaimer-policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> and it works with var privacyLink = document.querySelector('.htmlSection a#privacy_policy'); but the problem is that I can not add anything to the HTML as it is generated automatically by a form tool

Comment: Both versions work, when you combine them with selecting the link via its href content, as you already did before: https://jsfiddle.net/bL7fo5e6/ If the _rest_ of your script after selecting the correct link is still not working, then you'll have to do a bit more debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the change event on the select element and replace the part of the URL with the selected value.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.forms.form01.countrySelect.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let countryCode = e.target.value;
    let privacylink = document.getElementById('privacylink');
    privacylink.href = `https://www.example.com/${countryCode}/disclaimer-policies/privacy/`;
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <select name="countrySelect">
    <option value="uk" selected>UK</option>
    <option value="au">AU</option>
    <option value="sg">SG</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div class="htmlSection" id="tfa_34">
  <div class="htmlContent" id="tfa_34-HTML">
    <span style="font-size: 14.4px;">Your personal information will be processed in accordance with our <a id="privacylink" href="https://www.example.com/uk/disclaimer-policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```